# Spring JSP form to create table with checkboxes

Tags: spring, jsp

I have such a form:

```
    <form method="get" action="/nuvia/provisioning/>
<c-rt:forEach items="${pager.items}" var="subscriber">
  <tr>
    <td><form:checkbox class="select" path="items[${pos}].toDelete"/></td>
    <td><a href="${base}/${subscriber.id}"><c-rt:out value="${subscriber.firstName} ${subscriber.lastName}"/></a></td>
  </tr>
</c-rt:forEach>
                <input type="submit" value="List selected subscribers"/>
            </form>
```

Instead of having the form object how to make to send just selected checkbox indexes back to controller? so controller will receive just a collection of numbers without defining a command object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary objective of using Spring mvc is to bind command object with jsp page and pass it to controller.

For delete operation, you may require only ids, but you need command object for insert/update. Hence please change your code to use command object .